# Steamroller javascript code how to happen

Tags: javascript, arrays, flatten

pleases describe me recursion function how to happen flatten array in the final result. Mainly please describe in the if section

```js
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  let answer = [].concat(...arr);
  console.log(answer)
  if(answer.some(Array.isArray)){
    return steamrollArray(answer);
  }
  return answer
}

let result = steamrollArray([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]);
// console.log(result)
```

Comment: The `if` condition checks if `answer` (an array) has any element which satisfies `Array.isArray()`. If it helps, imagine it like so: `answer.some(function(x) { if (Array.isArray(x)) return true; return false; })`. Instead of writing an anonymous function, it's sufficient to simply write `Array.isArray` and JavaScript will return truthy or falsy based on the iterator being an array or not. If `answer` has any element which is an array, then `steamrollArray` is invoked (ie, recursive-call is made). Otherwise, since `answer` has no elements that is an array no recursion and simply return `answer`

Comment: thank you! Please can you sow me with Hierarchy what happen inside recursive-call in step by step

Answer (score 0):

Have added `console.log` to help with understanding how the recursion works. Introduced a variable `idx` to help track the level of recursion.

```js
function steamrollArray(arr, idx=0) {
  console.log('bgn--> recursion # ', idx);
  console.log('arr: ', JSON.stringify(arr));
  let answer = [].concat(...arr);
  console.log(
    'computed answer: ', JSON.stringify(answer)
  );
  if(answer.some(Array.isArray)){
    // "answer" has an array, so recurse to next level
    console.log(
      'at least ONE elt in "answer" is an array\n',
      '--> making recursive call from recursion #: ',
      idx
    );
    return steamrollArray(answer, idx+1);
  };
  console.log(
    'no elt in "answer" is an array\n',
    'no more recursion from recursion #: ', idx,
    ' answer: ', answer.join(),
    ' has ZERO arrays ...'
  );
  return answer;
}

let result = steamrollArray([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]);
// console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```